# Trigger GPU rasterization in Chrome from HTML/CSS for background image animation

Tags: html, css, performance, google-chrome, rendering

When it comes to certain operations, such as [animating CSS backgrounds with keyframes, Chrome is horribly CPU-intensive](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507015), compared to Firefox or IE (40% CPU and 60% GPU vs. 5% and 15%).

[This Chromium page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/how-to-get-gpu-rasterization) claims that to force GPU rasterization, you can add this tag to the HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

However, that is supposed to work only on some Android devices.

Is there a similar trigger for the desktop version of Chrome? The [null-transform hack](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/) didn't work in Chrome 43 ([full demo](http://codepen.io/dandv/pen/QbmbrW)).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/perforated_white_leather.png') repeat;
  background-size: 300px auto;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
  
  /* doesn't actually force GPU rasterization */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* for Opera, Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -300px 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code you can enable GPU accelerated rendering specifically on the elements selected by your css selectors, if a GPU is present.

One of the quickest ways is to apply a 3D transform to the element which will force most of the browsers (including desktop Chrome) to have a GPU accelerated compositing layer that includes the element.

For example:

```
.element {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

or

```
.element {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

If you want it only for `webkit` browsers, use the value with `-webkit-` only.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [null-transform hack](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/) didn't work. I've updated the question.

Comment: The vendors have changed things so you need something like will-change: transform, but in any case it won't affect animating a background-image.  Also, background-images tend to round to pixels in integer form, so transitioning via css or script will still 'click' pixel-by-pixel, rather than moving smoothly between positions.  Annoying, but maybe we'll be lucky and they'll change that soon.  That being said, Chrome is able to handle _a lot_ more 3d transforms than Firefox.  Make a bunch of animated cubes and Firefox will bog and get choppy, whereas Chrome will be smooth with twice as many.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but from what I understand, GPU rasterization won't help with animating a background.  I had a similar issue about a year ago, and finally resorted to animating a nested div with a low z-index, and put the background-image in there.  If you need to make it 'rollover' like a continuous motion, you re-position it toward center (original starting point) by the size of the actual image.

```
<div id=bg_container style="
  position: absolute;  left: 0px;  top: 0px;  right: 0px;  bottom: 0px; /* center, or place it however you want */
  width: 1000px;   height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
"><div id=bg_image style="
  position: absolute;  left: -1000px;  top: -1000px;
  width: 3000px;  height: 3000px;
  background-image: url(/myimage.png);
  background-size: 1000px 1000px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
"></div></div>
```

Put your css wherever you want, this is just a brief example.

Basically, this gives you a 1000px square div 'window' with a 3x3 grid of the image (i.e. 9 repeats, 3 X and 3 Y).  You want to animate the bg_image, basically however you did the background image you were originally trying to do.  This lets you move 1 full size of the container in any direction.  Then, if you need to appear like it's a continuous motion, subtract and/or add 1000px to it's X and Y position via translate3d().  The math to re-position should be the opposite of the directions you are animating it.